# Применить изменения к запущенному коду в Android Studio не перезагружая его

Tags: android-studio

Узнал что в Eclipse есть такая функция, как `code hot swapping`, которая применяет изменения к работающему коду без перезапуска. Хотелось бы использовать, если можно, нечто подобное в Android Studio. Кто знает, подскажите как реализовать.

Дополнение (**17.09.2023**):
Есть пара новостей. Перерыл все настройки (**Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1**, **SDK 33**, **JBR 17**) не нашел ничего что касается `Apply Code Changes` или `Instant Run`. Единственное что было, как я думаю, похожее на это `File` - `Settings` - `Build, Execution, Deployment` - `Debugger` - `HotSwap`, где я поставил все галочки кроме второго пункта `Enable 'JVM will hang' warning`.
Сборка проекта была с помощью **LibGDX** генератора (**Gradle 7.5.1**). Все это время я запускал код через `DesktopLauncher` (который собственно и создается через **LibGDX** генератор) и не было даже намеков на `Apply Changes` или `Instant Run`. При запуске через `Android Launcher` на физическом устройстве в панели быстро доступа появились функции `Apply Code Changes` и `Apply Code Changes and Restart Activity`, в частности `Apply Code Changes` выполняет то что мне и надо было изначально.
Так как мне удобней тестировать код через ПК не подключаясь к физическому устройству, как мне активировать данные функции, `Apply Code Changes` и `Apply Code Changes and Restart Activity`, при запуске проекта через `DesktopLauncher` на ПК?

Comment: Да, есть. Реализовывать не надо, там прямо на панели запуска есть кнопка.

Comment: Как называется кнопка или как выглядит, я ее по крайне мере не нашел.

Answer (score 0):

Меню `Run` - `Apply Code Changes`, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>.

Или `Run` - `Apply Code Changes and Restart Activity`, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>.

Comment: Эти способы я пробовал. В меню `run` нету `Apply Code Changes` и т.д., а комбинация клавиш вызывает рефакторинг метода (если курсор указывает на данный метод) или ничего не происходит если курсор не на коде.

Comment: File - Settings - Build, Execution, Deployment - Instant Run активирован? SDK какой версии используется?

Comment: Дополнил вопрос в ``Дополнение (17.09.2023)``